# How to replace opening and closing font tags with <Hn> tags programatically

Tags: html, linux, text, command, line

I am looking for a way to replace both opening and closing font tags with opening and closing `<Hn>` tags. For instance, I would like to change all occurences of the following:

```
`<font face="garamond" size="4" color="#000000">some text</font>`
```

to:

```
<H2>some text</H2>
```

There are lots of other font tags in the code so, simply looking for `<font face="garamond" size="4" color="#000000">` and replacing it with `<H2>` and then replacing `</font>` with `</H2>` will not work.
I have tried something like this:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/<font face="garamond" size="4" color="#000000">*<\/font>/<H2>*<\/H2>/g
```

but, it seems that my use of the asterisk is not a valid wildcard.
I have a large number of files and looking to do this recursively from a Linux command line. Thanks.

Comment: Editing HTML with Regex? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/636009

Comment: If you *are* going to go down this road, you need something like `\(.*\)` and `\1` in the sed match and replacement. But consider what happens if there's a line break in the opening tag, or the `size` and `color` attributes swap places...

Comment: I am not wedded to using regex if there is something else for the job. As for swapping of size/color, my objective is to remove all font tags (and replace them with appropriate H-tags) from the code so, I will find the other versions eventually. I just want to get them as efficiently as possible without having to go through hundreds of files with a fine toothed comb.